# How to get all property of a class

Tags: crystal-lang

I wish get all the properties of a class. 
When I pretty print an object, I have all the information of the object, so I suppose there is a way to get the properties of a class directly.

For example :

```
class Location
  property latitude : Float64
  property longitude : Float64
end
```

How do you determine that `Location` has latitude and longitude as properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal has no built-in option for retrieve methods but you can define it:

```
class Location
  property latitude  : Float64
  property longitude : Float64

  def initialize(@latitude, @longitude)
  end

  # Call this on class instance
  def methods
    {{ @type.methods.map(&.name).select { |m| !m.includes?("=") }.map(&.stringify)  }}
  end
end

loc = Location.new(-13.8948894, 33.775556)
pp loc.methods #=> ["latitude", "longitude", "initialize", "methods"]
```

`property` [is a macro](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/object.cr#L911) that will be unwrapped as getter/setter method in compilation and as result you can find it in the list of methods.

Comment: Here's a list of methods available on `@type`: https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.34.0/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html

Answer (score 2):

I also found this way

```
class Location
  property latitude  : Float64
  property longitude : Float64

  def initialize(@latitude, @longitude)
  end

  # Call this on class instance
  def methods
     {{ pp! @type.instance_vars  }}
  end
end

loc = Location.new(-13.8948894, 33.775556)
pp loc.methods #=> @type.instance_vars # => [latitude, longitude]
```

Comment: This should work as well as a class method, `def self.`